# Encoding ☺ as IBM-437 fails while other valid characters like é succeed

Tags: python, encoding, python-3.x, codepages

☺:

```
>>> bytes('☺','ibm437')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/encodings/cp437.py", line 12, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_map)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u263a' in position 0: character maps to <undefined>
```

As opposed to é, which works:

```
>>> bytes('é','ibm437')
b'\x82'
```

I expect ☺ to bring me back `b'\x01'`. How can I make this the case?

[An image of Code Page 437.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aCodepage-437.png)

Comment: Does `u'☺'.encode('ibm437')` work in Python 3? (It does in Python 2.)

Comment: @Cameron: that is what the OP is doing..

Comment: Hmm. Seems like `'☺'` is interpreted as `'\x01'` in Python 2 and `'\u263a'` in Python 3.

Comment: The IBM 437 codepage codepoints 1-31 are normally control codes (they map one-on-one to ASCII in many cases); only in a video context does that map to the smiley.

Comment: @Cameron For me it maps to `b'\x01'` both in Python2 and Python3. :(

Comment: @Cameron: `b'\x01'.decode('ibm437')` maps to `'\x01'` in Python 3 too.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Some more context might help: I have many files in this encoding that I'd like to "update" to Unicode so they can be more easily read on modern machines. I was hoping `\x01` would become ☺, but it does not. Is there an alternate way to convert these files (preferably using Python?)

Comment: From the WP page: *Implementers of translation to Unicode should note that these codes do not have a unique, single Unicode equivalent and the correct choice depends upon context*. I don't think you can provide that context for Python.

Comment: @Martijn: Yes, but the actual character literal `'☺'` evaluates to `'\x01'` in my Python 2 interpreter, but produces the above error (about `\u263a`) in a Python 3 interpreter. Possibly a different default source code encoding somewhere...

Comment: @Cameron What version of Python are you using, and on what OS? `u'☺'.encode('ibm437')` raises `UnicodeEncodeError` for me on Python 2.7.3 on Arch Linux.

Comment: @Cameron: are you perhaps running Python on Windows?

Comment: Try recoding your file using the [`recode` commandline utility](http://recode.progiciels-bpi.ca/); it has a IBM437 codec too.

Comment: The alternative is to use [`str.translate()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) to map each codepoint to a Unicode code point. The Wikipedia article does have a full table for those control codes interpreted in a graphical context including Unicode codepoints.

Comment: @Martijn: Ah, yes I am running on Windows (and the Python 3 prompt I used was online, probably on Linux). That's probably why :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

IBM-437 is somewhat special in that it is not only a codepage (i.e. defines what should happen for byte values 128-255), but also redefines some of the ASCII control characters, [but only in some contexts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437#Interpretation_of_code_points_1.E2.80.9331_and_127). Python maps those problematic codepoints to control characters, and not to the visible characters they were displayed as in some contexts.

To convert, you can use the following helper method:

```
ibm437_visible = lambda byt: byt.decode('ibm437').translate({
    0x01: "\u263A", 0x02: "\u263B", 0x03: "\u2665", 0x04: "\u2666",
    0x05: "\u2663", 0x06: "\u2660", 0x07: "\u2022", 0x08: "\u25D8",
    0x09: "\u25CB", 0x0a: "\u25D9", 0x0b: "\u2642", 0x0c: "\u2640",
    0x0d: "\u266A", 0x0e: "\u266B", 0x0f: "\u263C", 0x10: "\u25BA",
    0x11: "\u25C4", 0x12: "\u2195", 0x13: "\u203C", 0x14: "\u00B6",
    0x15: "\u00A7", 0x16: "\u25AC", 0x17: "\u21A8", 0x18: "\u2191", 
    0x19: "\u2193", 0x1a: "\u2192", 0x1b: "\u2190", 0x1c: "\u221F",
    0x1d: "\u2194", 0x1e: "\u25B2", 0x1f: "\u25BC", 0x7f: "\u2302",
})
assert ibm437_visible(b'\x01') == '☺'
```

Comment: thank for the translate table. i have a similar issue as OP: i want to transcode from 437 to utf-8 in java, it seems java doesn't translate 0x01 to `☺` too.

Comment: It appears that `decode` maps the byte values 0x00 through 0x1f directly to the identical code point.  What I find fascinating is that about half of those code points are very similar to the correct symbols, even if they aren't exact.