# How to convert \x after base64 decoding into something readable?

Tags: python, unicode, base64, ascii

I'm trying to decode the following Base64 string into readable text.

```
T2ggeWVhaCEgAQ==
```

I'm using Python Base64 library to do so. However, when I do, I get:

```
>>> base64.b64decode("T2ggeWVhaCEgAQ==")
'Oh yeah! \x01'
```

What is `\x01`?

How do I decode such that all the text is readable and I don't get any weird symbols?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'\x01'` is a text representation of `bytes` in Python 2. `'\x01'` is a single byte. Bytes that are in [ASCII printable range](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/isprint.html) represent themselves e.g., you see `'O'` instead of `'\x4f'`:

```
>>> b'\x4f\x68\x20\x79\x65\x61\x68\x21\x20\x01'
'Oh yeah! \x01'
```

To remove all "weird" bytes (to keep characters from `string.printable`):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import string

weird = bytearray(set(range(0x100)) - set(map(ord, string.printable)))
print(b'Oh yeah! \x01'.translate(None, weird).decode())
# -> Oh yeah!
```

`string.printable` contains some [non-printable characters](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/isprint.html) such as `'\t'` (tab), `'\n'` (newline). To exclude them too and to leave only [printing character](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/isprint.html):

```
printing_chars = range(0x20, 0x7e + 1)
weird = bytearray(set(range(0x100)) - set(printing_chars))
print(b'Oh yeah! \x01'.translate(None, weird))
# -> Oh yeah!
```

Comment: I get that `\x01` is a smiley face icon

Comment: `'\x01'` is not a smiley face icon. It is a byte (the numerical value is one). It is a control character. If you print it; it is invisible.

Comment: When I do `print 'Oh yeah! \x01'` in the Python console, I get: `Oh yeah! ☺`

Comment: I've enumerated all characters encodings available on my machine -- none produce the smiley for `'\x01'` (`u'\u263a'.encode(encoding)`). What is `sys.stdout.encoding` in your case? What is the font?

Comment: [yes, in cp437, it seems some control characters can be displayed differently](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437) in [some contexts](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14553297/4279). `b'\x01'.decode('cp437') == u'\x01' != u'\u263a'` and `u'\u263a'.encode('cp437')` raises `UnicodeEncodeError` my system. For a portable code, use Unicode: `print(u'Oh yeah! \u263a')` (to make it work on Windows, install `win-unicode-console` package)

Answer (score 1):

You could filter out the unreadable characters:

```
from string import printable
print ''.join(c for c in base64.b64decode('T2ggeWVhaCEgAQ==') if c in printable)
```

Answer (score 0):

The last byte of the Base64 encoded data is hex 01. This isn't a printable character in any commonly used encoding; there's no way to make it into "readable text" without turning it into something it isn't.